# How do I bind to Shift+{Left,Right} in tmux?

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux, key-mapping

I'm looking at `tmux` from `screen`, and have hit a bump while configuring the (highly configurable!) `tmux` key bindings.

Problem is, in my `.screenrc` I have

```
bindkey ^[[d prev
bindkey ^[[c next
bindkey ^[[a title
bindkey ^[[b screen 1
```

and the bindings work (they originally came from `rxvt-tabbedex`).

But in `tmux` there's apparently no way to bind commands to <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> combinations. Please prove me wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this (as a partial example):

```
bind -n S-Right next-window
bind -n S-Left previous-window
```

That should be enough to make it easy to get the other 2 settings working too.  It works on my tmux installation (1.4) but YMMV.

You can also use the meta key (option on Macs, alt on PCs):

```
bind-key -n M-Right next-window
bind-key -n M-Left previous-window
```

If you're using Terminal.app in OS X you need to enable the use of the option key in the Preferences for that to work.  (As far as I remember it works by default in iTerm, but if not it can definitely be enabled.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you were in my situation (windows desktop using putty on linux server) but I have the same problem.

I solve this issue using MobaXterm instead of putty and using "classic bind-keys":

```
bind-key -n C-right next
bind-key -n C-left prev
```